# Surface plot on Rectangular Mesh giving "ValueError"

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, surface

I'm trying to surface plot on a rectangular mesh. This is the code I have:

```
Z = np.reshape(FV,(N_x,N_y))
x = np.linspace(0,1,N_x)
y = np.linspace(0,1,N_y)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1,
                cmap='viridis', edgecolor='none')
```

I get the error:
`ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape`

This works only when N_x == N_y, how do I make it work when N_x != N_y?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens to be an artifact of the way [`numpy.meshgrid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) is implemented - check the notes on *indexing*.

The *y* variable changes along rows with the default indexing `'xy'` (and the *x* variable along columns, obviously!) - think about it geometrically - horizontal is *x*, vertical is *y*. So you have two possible solutions:

- Change `Z = np.reshape(FV,(N_x,N_y))` to `Z = np.reshape(FV,(N_y,N_x))`. Perhaps a little non-intuitive, but works fine.
- Use the keyword argument `indexing = 'ij'` with `np.meshgrid` to change to *x* variable varying along rows - something we are quite used to thinking about, when using matrices.